# Why didSelectItemAt is called with support when using GestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I am using colletcionView and UILongPressGestureRecognizer. cancelsTouchesInView set to false. The cell began to respond, but you also have to hold it in order for the didSelectItemAt method to work.

How to make the cell colletcionView respond immediately without delay?

```
func setupGestureRecognizer() {
        let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress))
        longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
        longPressRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
    }

@objc func longPress(longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
// code
}
```

Comment: Attach the long press recognizer to each cell, not to the table as a whole.

Comment: Couldn't be describing in more detail how it would look like? Thank!